# Find duplicate media files and auto organize, on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, archiving, deduplication, multimedia

Is there an application similar to MediaMoney (on Windows), but on Linux (Debian or Ubuntu) that given when a disk-drive or a root directory, can search across it thoroughly, identifying duplicate media files (photos, videos, music files). If it can do so smartly, s.a. identifying duplicates even if the filenames are different but content is same, it'd be very good. I am thinking of something that might compare crc of 2 files, magic number. If it can read meta-data as well, to compare, that'd be even better.

As for auto-organization, if it can do something merging, to create new organized directory, and deleting the duplicates - it'd be really helpful.

Comment: Here is a Link for you for this exact problem on Media Monkey's wiki. http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Linux,_Wine_%26_MediaMonkey

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to avoid WINE if possible. In past, I've not had a great experience with it, and it has led to some dependency hell to be unleashed.

Comment: This link (http://www.howtogeek.com/201140/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-files-on-linux/) talks of some good native options.

Answer (score 0):

[rmlint](http://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is linux-native, very fast and gives you lots of options for deciding which file (out of each duplicate set) is the "original".  It uses SHA1 (160 bit) checksum by default but can also do byte-by-byte comparison.

Unfortunately it's not in the Ubuntu/Debian repositories, but installation is fairly easy (see instructions [here](http://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html)).